# Why do methods like List/Map/Set.of(...) or Arrays.asList(...) return an immutable list?

Tags: java, list, java-9

What is the reasoning behind returning a *immutable* list instead of a mutable list?

Comment: `Arrays.asList` does not return an immutable list. It returns a fixed-length list because it is wrapping the explicit array it is given.

Comment: Why return a mutable list?

Comment: e.g. for practical reasons. Maybe I want to add or delete elements afterwards - I just don‘t get the point why there is this restriction to not be able to do so.

Comment: Immutability is _good_ because it protects you from shooting yourself in the foot.  For example, a `static final List` is really never appropriate to modify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Performance

Given below is the excerpt from [Oracle JDK 9 Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-DD066F67-9C9B-444E-A3CB-820503735951):

> For optimal performance, the immutable collections store a data set
> that never changes. However, you may be able to take advantage of the
> performance and space-saving benefits even if your data is subject to
> change. These collections may provide better performance than the
> mutable collections, even if your data changes occasionally.

[`List#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) are static factory methods which provide a **convenient way** to create **immutable** lists. In other words, it's a **convenience method** to create **immutable** lists. Prior to Java-9, this was possible through separate APIs like [`Collections#unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)).

If you want to get a mutable list, you can instantiate an `ArrayList` with this immutable list as the parameter.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("A", "B", "C"));
        mutableList.add("D");
        System.out.println(mutableList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[A, B, C, D]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer "*Why do methods like ... return an immutable list?*"